# Entity frameworks 6: Add multiple nested levels (> 3+)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework.
As I read on this [article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) and success to write a helloworld application. However, when design objects with many nested levels such as:

- School (1 - n) Teacher
- Teacher (1 - n) Class
- Class (1 - n) Student

And tried to add all elements at once, it **throws exception**. 
If I add only **School - Teacher**, then **Teacher - Class** ... It fine.

Here is an exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.SetCachedChangingValues(String entityMemberName, Object changingObject, String changingMember, EntityState changingState, Object oldValue)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.EntityMemberChanged(String entityMemberName, Object complexObject, String complexObjectMemberName)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.EntityMemberChanged(String entityMemberName)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateEntry.System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityChangeTracker.EntityMemberChanged(String entityMemberName)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.SnapshotChangeTrackingStrategy.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.SetCurrentEntityValue(StateManagerTypeMetadata metadata, Int32 ordinal, Object userObject, Object newValue)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateEntryDbUpdatableDataRecord.SetRecordValue(Int32 ordinal, Object value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DbUpdatableDataRecord.SetValue(Int32 ordinal, Object value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.PropagatorResult.SetServerGenValue(Object value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.BackPropagateServerGen(List`1 generatedValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction, Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__33()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass28.<SaveChanges>b__25()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at Repository.UnitOfWork.Save() in d:\Practice\DotNet\RelationShip\Repository\UnitOfWork.cs:line 44
at RelationShip.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Practice\DotNet\RelationShip\RelationShip\Program.cs:line 35
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that does the data operation and throws the exception?

Comment: The code you use to query the database is very important here, without it, we can't really help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this an extremely late answer, but today I got the same error. It is an obscure error that basically kind leaves you scratching your head without much information to figure out what's going on.

In my case I think it was caused by the fact that I had an entity with 3 primary key fields, 2 of which came from a parent table. The entity has a foreign key property pointing to the parent entity.

When I inserted these objects, I assigned the foreign key reference via the parent object, and I got the same error you've got upon calling SaveChanges. I had to do it this way because the parent object was new, and I did not know it's primary key field value until the object was actually saved in the database (it's primary key was an identity field).

What I ended up doing is I started a transaction, I executed the first SaveChanges that created the parent object, then assigned the 3 primary key fields values of the child object individually (rather then assigning the parent object + the 3rd PK field), then I called a second SaveChanges on the db context and it worked.

Maybe this will help someone else.